# Using Spring MessageListener to consume messages in groups?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I've got a spring app and I want to use [JMS Message Groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) to process JMS messages in specific blocks (and the same transaction, etc.).  Basically say I have 5 related events, I have a `JMSTemplate` that sends them with the same `JMSXGroupID` and sequential `JMSXGroupSeq` values.

I then have a `MessageProcessorService` defined in Spring that looks something like this:

```
<bean id="messageProcessorService" class="x.y.z.MessageProcessorService"/>
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" concurrency="5" >
    <jms:listener destination="messages.queue" ref="messageProcessorService" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

My `MessageProcessorService` is the standard, simple:

```
@Service
public class MessageProcessorService implements MessageListener {

public void onMessage(Message msg) { ... }
}
```

Problem is, since onMessage only gets 1 message at time.  How do I get all 5 of the messages in a particular group and then start processing them?

I know that I can use a negative `JMSXGroupSeq` value to mark the end of a group, then I was thinking I could keep a small list of messages and examine the Message `JMSXGroupSeq` and when it was -1 then process the whole group, but that seems a little hacky and not sure if its thread-safe (I definitely will need multiple threads processing in parallel).

Anyone else done something like this before in Spring/JMS/ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I found [this approach](http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2010/04/batchmessagelistenercontainer-using.html) and did a roughly similar thing. It was not pretty though.  I think longer term we might have to abandon the MessageListenerContainer and roll our own solution with direct JMS api's.

Comment: Brian, can you share some more information on how you were able to integrate the MessageListenerContainer? I am stuck at that point.
See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153102/how-to-specify-custom-jms-message-listener-in-spring-xml

Answer (score 0):

Great question. While message groups are great for some tasks they do not map that good onto message listeners.

You could go for your approach, to keep a list in memory of the messages. Threading safety won't be an issue if you create your Listener bean in the prototype scope.

```
<bean id="messageProcessorService" class="x.y.z.MessageProcessorService" scope="prototype"/>
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

You just need to keep some internal list of messages received in the class and they will be unique for that thread.

This depends a bit on what your transactional requirements are. Do you need to commit a transaction around the entire message group? Then you need to keep track of when to commit and when to not. IBM has made an example of this (not using ActiveMQ though) [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0602_currie/0602_currie.html) in Listing 5. It's not Spring but plain MDBs. Can't say it works the same with ActiveMQ though, so I leave no guarantees.